# Telnet to one computer from multiple computer

Tags: bash, shell, ping, telnet

I have scenario where I have list of 100s of server . Want to check whether those all server can reach to specified destination server or not by telneting from all server to that destination server.

I have written a code as below,

```
#!/bin/bash
#bash to check telnet status.
#set -x;
#
#clear
SetParam() {
export URLFILE="Host_PortFile.txt"
export TIME=`date +%d-%m-%Y_%H.%M.%S`
export port=80
export STATUS_UP=`echo -e "\E[32m[ RUNNING ]\E[0m"`
export STATUS_DOWN=`echo -e "\E[31m[ DOWN ]\E[0m"`
export MAIL_TO="admin(at)techpaste(dot)com"
export SHELL_LOG="`basename $0`.log"
}

Telnet_Status() {

SetParam

cat $URLFILE | while read next
do

server=`echo $next | cut -d : -f1`
port=`echo $next | awk -F":" '{print $2}'`

TELNETCOUNT=`sleep 5 | telnet $server $port | grep -v "Connection refused" | grep "Connected to" | grep -v grep | wc -l`

if [ $TELNETCOUNT -eq 1 ] ; then

echo -e "$TIME : Port $port of URL http://$server:$port/ is \E[32m[ OPEN ]\E[0m";
else
echo -e "$TIME : Port $port of URL http://$server:$port/ is \E[31m[ NOT OPEN ]\E[0m";
echo -e "$TIME : Port $port of URL http://$server:$port/ is NOT OPEN" | mailx -s "Port $port of URL $server:$port/ is DOWN!!!" $MAIL_TO;

fi
done;
}
Main() {
Telnet_Status
}
SetParam
Main | tee -a $SHELL_LOG
```

My Host_PortFile.txt file looks like,

```
gmail.com:443
```

But here, i need to go to individual server and  has to run this which consumes more time. Is there any modification I can do so that I can run the script from one machine to read all source server name from text file or any and can check that server can reach the destination server or not? Can anyone suggest on this please?

Comment: Use a software for system monitoring.

Comment: Use `GNU Parallel` to get them all checked in parallel, just put `GNU parallel` into Stack Overflow's search box.

Comment: from the common host if ssh is allowed to all the other servers, you can probably do ssh username@host "telnet destinationServer Port".
read the hostnames from a file using while loop.